# How can I fix the error a value of type 'XFile?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image-picker

The error is this : ***A value of type 'XFile?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'***. I tried changing the type of the variable "picture", from File to XFile, and it gives me this error instead: ***A value of type 'XFile?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'XFile'***.

This is my code so far:

```dart
void _openCamera() async {
    if(imagenes.length == 8) {
      alerta(contextMain, 'Limites de imagenes');
    }
    else {
      
      File picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 75);
      int pos = imagenes.length;

      imagenes.add({pos:picture});
      setState(() {});
      await jsonBloc.cargarImagen( picture ).then((value) {
        int id = value; 
        imagenes[pos] = { id: picture };
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get file like

```dart
XFile? picture = await ImagePicker()
    .pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 75);
if (picture != null) {
  final File imageFile = File(picture.path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ImagePicker.pickImage` is a Future that returns an `XFile?`, which means it can either return an actual `XFile`, or `null`.

So your variable `picture` needs to be an `XFile?` as well. So keep in mind in the rest of your code that `picture` can be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the package ([image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) ) you are using is relying on XFile and not File, as previously done.

So, first, you have to create a variable of type File so you can work with it later as you did, and after fetching the selectedImage you pass the path to instantiate the File. Like this:

```
File? selectedImage;

bool _isLoading = false;
CrudMethods crudMethods = CrudMethods();

Future getImage() async {
var image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

setState(() {
  selectedImage = File(image!.path); // won't have any error now
});
}

//implement the upload code
```